# Which Stack Exchange site is for knowing about API calls or API endpoints?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I already posted this question about API calls or endpoints, [on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45009783/ebay-api-is-there-any-api-call-or-endpoint-to-get-custom-shipping-rate-tables), however, it was marked as off-topic.

So where should I post such questions where answers can be expected from users who are already aware or have tried their hands at this?

Comment: may be webapps. not sure. read their help and ask first

Comment: I am of the opinion that it was "skimm close voted", at SO; that is, users read *a few select words*, and voted without careful reading. Your question was a bit poorly written, but at no point did it ask for a recommendation of any sort, which is why it was originally closed. *I believe they think you were asking for an API recommendation*.

Comment: Also note the edit, here; We do not need to see the question, itself, and thus it is irrelevant. [tag:api] is also irrelevant, as the tag does not apply to your question, in its intended usage.

Comment: @Gnemlock, Thank you so much for both the edits and very useful suggestions.

Comment: @SagarV: Definitely _not_ [webapps.se]. API questions are programming problems, and Web Apps is very much _not_ for programming.

Comment: @ale the question anyway get closed in SO

Comment: @SagarV: And? That doesn't mean it's automatically on-topic somewhere else. It would be closed at Web Apps, too.

Comment: @SagarV, the question got closed as "seeking a recommendation", and the user has since been told the question is still off-topic for "shows no research effort". IMO, this question was closed as "cant be bothered to read the actual question, and cant be bothered to make minor improvements to help new users"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### You're asking how to use a programming API; I would still say [*Stack Overflow*](https://stackoverflow.com).

You're asking how to perform a specific function within the ebay-api. In turn, you're asking how to *use* the ebay-api. For that reason, I would still say Stack Overflow. In fact, they have an explicit ebay-api tag, which you have used in your question.

What your question fails to convey is that you're *asking how to use the API*. It *actually* reads like your asking for a *recommendation* of an API, given a set requirement of needing to be able to draw out specific data. Granted, careful reading makes it clear that your asking for help with the API, but I cannot help but understand why users would *gloss over* it, and interpret it as a *recommendation* question.

I am suggesting an edit to your question, which I believe will make it clearer what you're *actually* asking. At that point, I believe you should ask about your question being closed as off-topic on the [Stack Overflow Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com).

#### In response to the feedback presented by [your question in Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/352351/request-to-reopen-question-on-ebay-api-call-implementation-which-has-been-mark)

With the question edited, and the meta question posted, further feedback has been requested. What I am about to say is *mostly* my opinion, unpopular as it may be.

Firstly, It was my suggestion that you ask about your question being closed as off-topic. It was *not* my suggestion that you ask for your question to be *reopened*. The key difference, here, is that you should be asking for further feedback. You should *not* be immediately jumping to the conclusion that your question is on-topic, and should be reopened.

This brings me to my personal opinion; realistically, Stack Overflow is the *last* place you should be asking your question. It is still the *best* place to ask your question, *on the Stack Exchange network*; but not all questions are fit for the Stack Exchange network. The thing is, there is a great debate on the decline of Stack Overflow. In my personal opinion, users are far less helpful, and far more elitist; especially in comparison to the many other stack sites. I have even seen stack sites that acknowledge this, by loosening their rules simply so that fewer users were told that *Stack Overflow* was the better option for their question.

Ultimately, you have been told that your question is off-topic because it shows no research effort, and still asks for a recommendation. This is *despite* the fact that "shows no research effort" is a hard written reason for *downvotes*, but *not* close votes. This is *despite* the fact that you show several references to documents you have viewed over (and the *amount* of effort is insignificant to debate, as "none" is always significantly less than "some"). This is despite the fact that we have edited your question to highlight the fact that you are already using a very specific API, and are asking for help with a *very specific function* of this very specific API.

#### TL;DR

At the end of the day, Stack Overflow is the best *Stack Exchange* site for your question; but they do not want it. There really is not much more you can do, I am afraid. I personally steer clear of Stack Overflow for this very reason. All that said, there appears to be an [eBay Developers Forum](https://forums.developer.ebay.com/). This might be a good avenue for seeking help, in regards to the eBay API.

Comment: He's not asking how to use the API, he is asking if such API (for his/her purpose) exists or not. And that is off-topic.

Comment: @Tom OP clearly asking about specific API, which is related to programming. Not sure it fits SO, but it is part of programming, so the answer is proper.

Comment: @Tom, you provide a very good example of how a skim reader could make this presumption. The question very specifically notes that the asker is "using the eBay API" (I.E. "dont recommend another API, I am using the eBay API) (it's even tagged as such). The question also specifically asks if there is a call or endpoint in said API. *He even goes so far as to link the specific API's documentary, to show users what he has tried*. At no point does the question *ask* for an alternate API (unless my definition of "Endpoint" is wrong).

Comment: @Tom, I was certainly NOT asking for any recommendation or alternate API, rather I was looking for specific call and implementation of eBay API itself.

Comment: @Gnemlock, I have asked about my question on [Stack Overflow Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/352351/request-to-reopen-question-on-ebay-api-call-implementation-which-has-been-mark)

Comment: @Sam, I have updated my answer with personal opinion. Unpopular as that opinion may be, there has always been some stigma surrounding SO. Sorry to say, but it doesn't look like this is a good place for your question.